# How Can Spring/Hibernate Access Private Members?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

As you know, Spring can inject values to private instance variables, and Hibernate can access private variables of persistent classes. However, I can't even call protected methods of a class through reflection! How can Spring and Hibernate blatantly breach security like that? And more importantly, how do I do it? :D

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391256/how-java-jaxb-works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When running without prohibitive security manager, you can obtain instance of corresponding method or field trough reflection and call [setAccessible()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) on it.

Using Java security manager you can of course disable that by writing a custom policy.

Answer (score 3):

You can set private a variable of another object through reflection. Here is an example on how to do it. Consider the following object with a private variable:

```
public class MyBean {
    private String message;
}
```

Normally the *message* field wouldn't be accessible from outside *MyBean*, however, *SnoopyClass* can set and get its value. I wrote two static methods: `setValue` which can set a *value* into a private field called *fieldName* of an Object *bean* and a `getValue` method which can get the value of a private variable called *fieldName* from an Object *bean*.

The *main* method just demonstrates its use by creating an Object of MyBean class, setting the *message* variable and retrieving it. I've actually tested this code as a standalone application and it works.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class SnoopyClass {

    private static void setValue(Object bean, String fieldName, Object value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, 
            SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Field privateVar = bean.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        privateVar.setAccessible(true);
        privateVar.set(bean, value);
    }

    private static Object getValue(Object bean, String fieldName) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Field privateVar = bean.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        privateVar.setAccessible(true);
        return privateVar.get(bean);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException,
            IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
         MyBean instance = new MyBean();
         setValue(instance, "message", "Shht! Don't tell anyone!");
         System.out.println("The message is '" + getValue(instance, "message"));
    }

}
```

The implementation uses `getDeclaredField` method on the class of the Object, because this method can look for all fields, even private. In contrast, `getField` can only access public members. The next step is calling `setAccessible` on the field to allow reading and writing it. The last step, is simply use the `get` and `set` methods provided by the `java.lang.reflect.Field` class.

This kind of manipulation is allowed only if the security manager allows that. By default Java doesn't install any security manager, so in a standalone program that you launch through your IDE or the command line, you won't have any problems to use this technique. I've also tried, in a Spring Application under Tomcat, and it's still working.

The primary application, at least for me, is being able to set private variables in my unit tests, especially for Spring Beans, without polluting the interface with unneeded setters.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can access private members via the 'field' level access configuration mechanism.  From the documentation, section [5.1.11](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html)

"The access attribute allows you to control how Hibernate accesses the property at runtime. By default, Hibernate will call the property get/set pair. If you specify access="field", Hibernate will bypass the get/set pair and access the field directly using reflection."