# What are design patterns to load DDD entity from Google Datastore?

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, google-cloud-datastore

I'm learning DDD and trying to implement Repository using Google Datastore.

I find recreating DDD entities from datastore quite tricky. I've read there are frameworks to map my DDD entities to datastore entities, but I would like to learn low-level API first.

I though, the repository could set the state of an entity using setters, but this is often considered anti-pattern in DDD.

An alternative would be to use builder pattern, where builder instance is passed to the constructor of an entity. However, this introduce to the entity a functionality (restoring entity state) that is out of its responsibility.

What are good patterns to solve problem?

Comment: What language are you using? Python?

Comment: It is the first time I heard that using setter is an anti-pattern for DDD.  I think it should be fine using setter.  However you should use the entity through the interface with business meaning, instead of using the implementation full of setter/getter.  I don't see any reason why this can be an anti-pattern of DDD

Comment: @Adrian Shum, I've seen lots of such claims on the Web: ["No other class should be allowed to change the state of an entity, other than that entity itself. Other entities/classes can only trigger a business method and during execution of that business method,the entity itself mutates its state."](http://stochastyk.blogspot.com/2008/05/entities-in-ddd.html). However, I agree with you that keeping setters/getter only at implementation level solves the problem perfectly.

Comment: @Adrian Shum having _public_ setters only for setting data during reconstitution can be an anti-pattern, but it can be addressed by having private setters that are called via reflection during reconstitution.

Comment: @eulerfx, why making the things complex with reflection if you can simply put *public* setters in implementation and do not put them in interface?

Comment: That might be an idiomatic Java approach, but it requires an interface declaration. With the reflection approach, you can have a single object representing the entity.

Comment: @eulerfx You missed my point.  Actual "user" of domain entity should access through interface.  Of course, in interface, we are NOT providing setters to user.  Public setters is something declared in the entity IMPLEMENTATION, for which is only used by repository.  If you understand the reason behind the 'anti-pattern' you will understand why I said my suggested approach is not the anti-pattern you are worrying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answer mainly coming from my comment in OP, but I think better to elaborate in an answer)

Setters are fine.  The problem is the "user" of the domain entity shouldn't access through those getter/setter.  The domain entity should have a business meaningful interface, so that the application logic is built base on this.  Setters should be something in the implementation level, which is used to create the implementation object (in repository etc)

I believe it is better to illustrate using an example.

---

This is the incorrect way for setter which consider to be anti pattern

```
class OrderApplicationService {
  public void cancelOrder(String orderId) {
    Order order = orderRepository.getOrder(orderId);
    order.setOrderStatus(CANCELLED);
    order.setOpenQuantity(0);
    orderRepository.update(order);
  }
}
```

---

However the more correct way is:

```
// Interface for Order

interface Order {
  void cancel();

  // no setters!!!
}

class OrderImpl extends Order {
  @Override
  void cancel() {
    this.status = CANCELLED;
    this.openQuantity = 0;
  }

  void setId(String orderId) { ... }
  // some other setters
}

class OrderApplicationService {
  public void cancelOrder(String orderId) {
    Order order = orderRepository.getOrder(orderId);
    order.cancel();
    orderRepository.update(order);
  }
}
```

Repository is creating and accessing through impl, so that it have access to the getters/setters.  However, your application logic is facing the interface only, and you are not implementing your logic using setters/getters (which is the anti-pattern)

---

The above way is enforcing through proper declaration of interface.  However, if you think you can rely on the self-reputation, you can simplify the story by having both the business-logic-related methods and setters/getters directly in Impl, omitting the interface.  And during your implementation, you should know that you should only use the business methods of entity (not getters/setters) during your business logic implementation.

---

And, it is not a simple rule-of-thumb to consider setters to be anti-DDD.  In some case, for example, storing a free text comment in an entity, providing a setter as business-logic-method does not necessary to be a wrong decision.

Answer (score 2):

The whole Chapter 6 of Eric Evans [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) is devoted to the problems you are describing.

First of all, Factory in DDD doesn't have to be a standalone service -

> Evans DDD, p. 139:
>
> There are many ways to design FACTORIES. Several special-purpose
>   creation patterns - FACTORY METHOD, ABSTRACT FACTORY, and BUILDER -
>   were thoroughly treated in Gamma et. al 1995. <...> The point here is
>   not to delve deeply into designing factories, but rather to show the
>   place of factories as important components of a domain design.

Each creation method in Evans FACTORY enforces all invariants of the created object, however, object reconstitution is a special case

> Evans DDD, p. 145:
>
> *A FACTORY reconstituting an object will handle violation of an invariant differently.* During creation of a new object, a FACTORY should simply balk when invariant isn't met, but a more flexible response may be necessary in reconstitution.

This is important, because it leads us to creating separate FACTORIES for creation and reconstitution. (in the diagram on page 155 *TradeRepository* uses a specialized *SQL TradeOrderFactory*, not a general general purpose *TradeOrderFactory* )

So you need to implement a separate logic for reconstitution, and there are several ways to do it
(You can find the full theory in Martin J Fowler [Patterns Of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420), on page 169 there's a subheading **Mapping Data to Domain Fields**, but not all of methods described look suitable(for example making the object fields package-private in java is seems to be too intrusive) so I'd prefer only one of the following two options

- You can create a separate FACTORY and document it so that developers should only use it only for persistence or testing.
- You can set the private field values with reflection, as for example [Hibernate does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127365/how-can-spring-hibernate-access-private-members).

<sub>Regarding the anemic domain model with setters/and getters, [the upcoming  Vaughn Vernon book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577) criticizes this approach a lot so I dare say it *is* an antipattern in DDD.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer. In [anemic domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) the problem lies not in using setters and getters in domain object, but in using *only* settings and getters without implementing business logic in them.

Comment: @dzieciou The approach of implementing business logic in getters and setters is very questionable. Yes, setters *can* encapsulate something - that is the access to the field(that is ok as an example for  classroom encapsulation for students) - but most business domains are not about setting field values. DDD promotes INTENTION REVEALING INTERFACES(it's one of the DDD patterns) - but what intent can setting a value reveal? You can't know it until you read the implementation - so the behavior of the program becomes unpredictable - this approach is the worst of DDD and data-centric worlds.

Comment: I meant in the domain objects, not in getters and setters. See the linked Wikipedia article. The order of words in my sentence was confusing.