# How to marshal/unmarshal Java objects with private fields using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I know the basics of the JAXB API, but I am stuck with something I am trying to do, and I am not sure whether it is actually possible. Details are as follows:

I have a class called **Book** with 2 *public* instance variables of type String:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="book")
public class Book
{
    public String title;
    public String author;

    public Book() {
    }
}
```

I have a another class called **Bookshop** with 1 *public* instance variable of type ArrayList:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="bookshop")
public class Bookshop
{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="book_list")
    @XmlElement(name="book")
    public ArrayList<Book> bookList;

    public Bookshop() {
        this.bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Note: package declaration and imports are removed in order to save space.

These two classes work and the output XML I get is something like:

```
<bookshop>
    <book_list>
        <book>
            <title>Book 1</title>
            <author>Author 1</author>
        </book>
        <book>
            <title>Book 2</title>
            <author>Author 2</author>
        </book>
    </book_list>
</bookshop>
```

As far as I know, instance variables need to be declared public in order for its class to be serialisable. Or, instance variables can be declared private, but accessors and mutators are needed in that case.

I don't like declaring instance variables public; I like using accessors and mutators. Even then, I want some of my fields to be read-only, i.e., no mutator. But JAXB seems to require both accessors and mutators for each field you want to marshal/unmarshal. I was wondering if there is any way around this?

Comment: Doesn't jaxb use reflection?

Comment: Looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391256/how-java-jaxb-works, it should just work fine with private fields

Comment: Yes, it uses reflection; maybe I need to add XML attribute to each instance field (public, private or protected)

Comment: Here is a blog post that will help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should keep your fields private in any case. You have 2 options binding to fields

1) annotate your fields with XmlElement or XmlAttribute annotation

```
@XmlRootElement(name="book")
public class Book {
    @XmlElement
    private String title;
    ...
```

2) annotate your class with @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="book")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Book {
         private String title;
         ...
```

Comment: This actually works for both marshalling and unmarshalling, the only thing i had to do was to add "@XmlElement" on top of my instance variable declarations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @temelm - If you specify `@XmlAcessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` the you won't need to put `@XmlElement` on the field.  If you choose the default accessor type and annotate the field remember that the corresponding get/set combination will also be mapped by default.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan - which one is a better practice? Or does it just come down to a personal preference?

Comment: @temelm - Mostly personal preference.  One area where it matters is when mapping JPA entites as some JPA implementations manipulate the byte codes so that the `get` methods lazily load data.  This means that when field access is used some data may be missed as it won't get loaded.

Comment: I think it does not matter for my case but this could be something that might be handy :) Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

JAXB will need either:
- A public instance variable
Or
- A private instance variable with public mutators and accessors.

You will need mutators for marshalling and acessors for unmarshalling

Comment: It does not break if there are no mutators but the values for those fields become 'null'. So mutators are a must?

Comment: They are, indeed. Think about it as an Object and forget about JAXB. How will you modify an instance variable marked private without a mutator (either programmatically or by reflection if it was JAXB who accesses to it)

Comment: what you say makes sense but I thought the whole point of JAXB was to be able to do simple XML serialization/deserialization no matter what our model is; and as Evgeniy Dorofeev pointed out, this actually is possible.