# Completly new to XML and JAXB. How do I go about unmarshalling this snippet?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This is a sample of the XML I've got. It contains several more rows with item

```
<items>
    <item name="Alfa Romeo">
        <models>
            <model to="2001" since="1994" name="145/146" />
            <model since="2001" name="147" />
            <model to="1997" since="1992" name="155" />
            <model since="1997" name="156" />
            <model since="2007" name="159" />
            <model to="1998" since="1990" name="164" />
            <model since="1999" name="166" />
            <model since="2004" name="GT" />
            <model since="1996" name="GTV" />
            <model to="2007" since="1996" name="Spider" />
            <model since="2007" name="Spider" />
        </models>
    </item>
    <item name="Fiat">
        <models>
            <model since="1995" name="Barchetta" />
            <model since="2007" name="Bravo" />
            <model since="1995" name="Bravo and Brava" />
            <model to="1998" since="1993" name="Cinquecento" />
            <model to="2000" since="1995" name="Coupe" />
            <model since="2001" name="Doblo" />
            <model since="2007" name="Grande Punto" />
            <model to="2007" since="2004" name="Idea" />
            <model to="2001" since="1997" name="Marea" />
            <model since="1999" name="Multipla" />
            <model since="2004" name="Panda" />
            <model to="2003" since="1994" name="Punto" />
            <model since="2003" name="Punto" />
            <model to="2004" since="1998" name="Seicento" />
            <model since="2002" name="Stilo" />
            <model to="1996" since="1991" name="Tempra" />
            <model to="1996" since="1989" name="Tipo" />
            <model to="2003" since="1995" name="Ulysse" />
        </models>
    </item>
</items>
```

Is it posible to unmarshall this into objects of Model with fields private int to; private int since; private String name; contained in an ArrayList inside models of Car(item) contained in an ArrayList?

Alternatively with objects of Car with fields private String brand(name); private int since; private int to; private String model(name) contained in an ArrayList?

If so how? or if not how other way can I retrieve the information into objects and a data structure?

I've started going through the very basic tutorials to learning JAXB, so I'm getting there step by step, but I would really like to be able to use this XML data in another java project I'm working on as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by generating you POJO's.  You can use an online tool to do this if you haven't done this already, see [How to generate JAXB classes from just XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995466/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-just-xml)

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with "private" explanation.  First step, get it to unmarshall.  You can then change decorations to make appropriate private fields - see [How to marshal/unmarshal Java objects with private fields using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240734/how-to-marshal-unmarshal-java-objects-with-private-fields-using-jaxb)

Essentially, use `@XmlElement` on private members:

```
public class model {
  @XmlAttribute
  private String to;
```